# How to wait for CodePipeline to deploy the function in Cloudformation

Tags: python-3.x, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, aws-cloudformation-custom-resource

I have a Cloudformation template and I wanted to create Aurora(MySQL) tables through it. However, there is [no built-in resource](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27360122/4636715) for it. So, I decided to build a **custom resource** function to create tables upon DbCluster creation. Moreover, as CI/CD Pipelines can also be created by Cloudformation, I prepared a template like below. However, it throws an error:

> Function not found: arn:aws:lambda:eu-central-1:xxxxxxxxxxxx:MyFunctionName (Service: AWSLambda; Status Code: 404; Error Code: ResourceNotFoundException; Request ID: ...)

Apparently, the CustomResource runs whenever Pipeline is created. But I need to wait for its first deployment of function in order to use it in custom resource. Thought the property `RestartExecutionOnUpdate: true` in `AWS::CodePipeline::Pipeline` and adding `DependsOn` in `Custom::RdsBootstrap` would help but they did not.

```
Resources:
  # Serverless Aurora DB Cluster
  MyDbCluster:
    Type: AWS::RDS::DBCluster
    ...

  # Build Project
  MyCustomResourceFunctionBuildProject:
    Type: AWS::CodeBuild::Project
    ...

  # Pipeline for deploying Custom Resource Function Source Code
  MyCustomResourceFunctionPipeline:
    Type: AWS::CodePipeline::Pipeline
    Properties:
      Name: custom-resource-function-pipeline
      RestartExecutionOnUpdate: true
      Stages:
        - Name: Source
          ...
        - Name: Build
          ...
        - Name: Pipeline
          ...

  # Custom Resource Function
  RdsBootstrap:
    Type: Custom::RdsBootstrap
    DependsOn: [MyDbCluster, MyCustomResourceFunctionPipeline]
    Version: '1.0'
    Properties:
      ServiceToken: !Sub "arn:aws:lambda:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:function:MyFunctionName"
```

So, how to make the custom resource not only wait for CodePipeline creation; but also its initial deployment?

Comment: You can't define a custom resource in the same template that uses the custom resource. Define it somewhere else - maybe you have a stack of custom resources, or some other stack where resources used by other stacks are created. Define it there, then you can use it in all the templates that need that functionality.

Comment: I think, you can use 'continuationToken' from the function to do your custom actions. Specifically in your case, you can return the continuationToken to your codepipeline if the function's status is 'In_Progess' or so. Codepipeline waits and resend the trigger to check the status if that's completed. This will keep running until the function returns success status to the codepipeline. Note that, the maximum wait time for the CodePipeline is 1 hour so if your function takes more than an hour to run, then the above won't work for you.

Comment: If I understand correct you are doing the lambda function deployment via CodePipeline as cloudformation deploy but same time including the custom resource in the CloudFormation template used for pipeline why? better to include that with lambda and do the deployment same way you are doing now.